# Streaming protocol latency test, there are some questions

Tags: android, streaming, protocols

I had a experiment to compare end-to-end latency of RTSP and RTMP.

Experiment is same below.

Constraint

- Network environments are same.
- use Wowza Media Streaming Engine as the media server.
- use VLC player as the streaming player.

Experiment 1.

1) Using Larix Broadcaster(Android App), send a RTSP stream to media server.

2) And then using VLC player, stream the video stream as a RTSP stream.

3) result end-to-end latency - 1.53 second

Experiment 2.

1) Same as Experiment 1-1.

2) Same as Experiment 1-2, but stream the video stream as a RTMP stream.

3) result end-to-end latency - 3.54 second

Experiment 3.

1) Using Wowza Gocoder(Android App), send a RTMP stream to media server.

2) And then using VLC player, stream the video stream as a RTSP stream.

3) result end-to-end latency - 1.3 second

Experiment 4.

1) Same as Experiment 3-1.

2) Same as Experiment 3-2, but stream the video stream as a RTMP stream.

3) result end-to-end latency - 3.47 second

Experiment Summary

- Input---Output---Latency

  RTSP---RTSP---1.53

  RTSP---RTMP---3.54

  RTMP---RTSP---1.3

  RTMP---RTMP---3.47

According to this result, I can find that the input streaming protocol doesn't have a effect on end-to-end latency.

But as I know, regardless of input or output, the latency that a streaming protocol should have is same. Isn't that right?

If it isn't, then why? Or if it is, then how can explain the result of experiment above?

Answer (score 0):

No, each streaming protocols is different, and it does not have the same latency.

There are many factors to considere here, not only the protocol itself, but the implementation or configuration in the client. 
I do not know exactly how VLC plays RTMP,  maybe (I do not know) the VLC is configured to have bigger buffer for RTMP than RTSP.

I can tell you that using WOWZA, and Flowplayer I had tests with less than 1 second delay. Using special configuration in Wowza and in the Flowplayer.